# How to write jest test script to check the value of constants

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a list of constants defined like this

```
const actions = {}
// Home
actions.HOME = {}
actions.HOME.SET_PROFILE_ID = 'SET_PROFILE_ID'
actions.HOME.LOAD_PROFILE = 'HOME_LOAD_PROFILE'
actions.HOME.SET_PROFILE = 'HOME_SET_PROFILE'

actions.OUTSIDE = {}
actions.OUTSIDE.UPDATE_PROFILE_ID = 'SET_PROFILE_ID' // this should error

module.exports = actions
```

The objects with in objects is to help intelisense so devs can narrow down as they go.

I want to use jest to write a test that will check to make sure no 2 constants have the same value, no matter the depth, otherwise it can create very odd errors that are hard to debug at run time.  I don't really understand the documentation and how I can do this.  https://jestjs.io/docs/en/using-matchers  But this is my first time making any unit tests.

Thank you

-Edit

This is what I have so far.  Based on Jared Smiths comments, I am no where close to the right answer as this is too simple.  It only finds the first mistake, not all of them.

```
describe('Actions.js', () => {
  it('verify no duplicate action values', () => {
    const flattenActions = []
    _.forEach(actions, store => {
      _.forEach(store, action => {
        flattenActions.push(action)
      })
    })
    const testedActions = []
    _.forEach(flattenActions, action => {
      expect(testedActions).not.toContain(action)
      testedActions.push(action)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: You are picking a rather challenging problem for your first foray into unit testing... you'll have to do a recursive search through all the properties and keep a running set of existing ones that throws if it finds a dupe. You could also use a typescript enum... if you were using typescript.

Comment: @JaredSmith I do usually jump both feet into the deep end of the pool.  It's how I tend to learn.

Comment: That works up to a point, but your question involves tree search, how to reliably keep track of the node values you've already seen, general testing practice, the specific API of jest, etc. Sure you can cargo-cult code your way through, but you won't be able to apply much of it next time you have a related but slightly different problem.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm actually pretty good at learning by example, not by documentation.  If I know the problem code is solving, I find it trivial to apply it to other problems.  The issue is, I don't know the right questions to ask yet.  Seeing a bunch of examples where it's like 'does 9 = 9' aren't helpful because I can't mentally extend those into real world examples.  But I am able to take real world examples and work backwards.  Usually when I get an answer for SO, I spend a few days googling every bit of the code to see why something was done that way, and thus I learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A unit test of this complexity probably merits its own [`matcher`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers), which you could define recursively like this:

```js
expect.extend({
  toHaveUniqueValues(received) {
    const keys = []
    const values = new Set()

    function assertUniqueValues(object) {
      if (typeof object === 'object' && object !== null) {
        for (const key in object) {
          if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            keys.push(key)
            assertUniqueValues(object[key])
            keys.pop()
          }
        }
      } else if (values.has(object)) {
        throw new Error(`expected ${keys.join('.')} to not have duplicate value ${String(object)}`)
      }

      values.add(object)
    }

    try {
      assertUniqueValues(received)
      return {
        message: () => 'expected object to have duplicate values',
        pass: true
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return {
        message: () => error.message,
        pass: false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The message that goes with `pass: true`, as explained in the documentation, is in case the test is negated and the negation of the test fails. `Set` is preferred to `Array` for storing the values found so far, because lookup using [`has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) is O(1) time on average while using [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is O(n) time.

To use the above matcher in your case:

```js
describe('actions', () => {
  it('should not have duplicate values', () => {
    expect(actions).toHaveUniqueValues()
  })
})
```

In this case it will complete with the error:

```
expected OUTSIDE.UPDATE_PROFILE_ID to not have duplicate value SET_PROFILE_ID
```

Comment: This is perfect and thank you for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can get all the values of your `actions`

```
function getDeepValues(obj) {
let values = [];
for (const key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
        const subVals = getDeepValues(obj[key]);
        values = [...values, ...subVals];
    } else {
        values.push(obj[key]);
    }
}
  return values;
}
```

Will output something like this:

```
[ 'SET_PROFILE_ID', 
  'HOME_LOAD_PROFILE', 
  'HOME_SET_PROFILE', 
  'SET_PROFILE_ID' ]
```

And then you test if the array doesn't contain any duplicates:

```
function arrayHasNoDuplicate(arr) {
  return arr.every(num => arr.indexOf(num) === arr.lastIndexOf(num));
};
```

Now you have to run your tests:

```
describe('Actions.js', () => {
it('verify no duplicate action values', () => {
  const actionsArray = getDeepValues(actions);
  const hasNoDuplicates = arrayHasNoDuplicate(actionsArray);
  expect(hasNoDuplicates).toBeTruthy();
  })
})
```

Hope it helps!